# How do I get a cable to realistically follow the back of my security camera when it moves?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh

I want this cable to stay attached to the post and the security camera while the camera rotates. I would like to prevent unrealistic stretching. I've tried using hooks with vertex groups but the end caps just stretch and the cable doesn't move. I'm not sure if I need cloth physics or soft body physics or something else.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way to do it is to use a curve for the cable.

You can hook the curve handle linked to the camera to an empty. Then parent this empty to another one driving the camera rotation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a very straightforward explanation, and the accompanied file was more than I expected!

Comment: I have it behaving that way you have taught, but when the security camera is turned in a more extreme way the cable clips into the camera box. Is there an easy way to keep that from happening? Would some sort of rigidbody have to be applied? I also parented the bottom handle of the bezier to the post, but it distorts/rotates a bit when the cable stretches. Is there a way to keep it more stiff at the bottom?

Comment: Update-- I think I mostly fixed the bottom part of the cable distortion by hooking it to an empty in the post instead and then playing with the scale and location of that empty a bit.