# Wires in Blender

Tags: bezier-curves

I am using Blender 2.90 and yesterday I thought about creating wires in Blender. I searched for some time and found out that it can be done using curves and arrays. There are many important aspects, so I can't remember all of them. But after some time I got that:
[image: Wire done using curve and array]

Then I went further and thought that it will be good if curve will change it's geometry while wire's source is moving. I did it with hooks, and it worked fine. But when I wanted to rotate a source, curve goes distorted:
[image: Distorted wire]

It looks like curve's hooked vertex changes it's position, but not rotation. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use curves, an example here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195051/how-do-i-get-a-cable-to-realistically-follow-the-back-of-my-security-camera-when/195054#195054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When you need to hook curve's **vert**, be sure to select all *verts* linked to the **vert** (not all of them will be shown until you choose a **vert**). For example, red circles are mistakes, green ones are the right hooking:
[image]
Also choose an object that will be the hook (will be followed by **vert**). It can be any object, ***Mesh*** or ***Empty Object*** (like on a picture) etc.

Have fun!